# Javascript Element to string

Tags: javascript

I am creating div element like below and inserting some html content inside div and innerText.

```
var creatediv=document.createElement("DIV");
var html="<div align="left"><a id="test" >test</a></div>";
creatediv.innerHTML=html;
creatediv.innerText="testing";
```

Now my question is how to retrieve the updated html variable here.

Thanks,

Raj

Comment: As a side note: `"<div align="left"><a id="test" >test</a></div>"`is not escaped properly.

Comment: You aren't changing the `html` variable, so what do you mean by "updated"? And you do realize you are actually creating a `div` inside of a `div`, right?

Comment: @polarblau:Yes your right,Here i want approach to achieve the above scenario.

Comment: @Travis Webb:Updated means ,after creating html div element,i am inserting html content.Within that html content i want to insert value as testing.After updating value,i want to retrieve html content i inserted before.

Comment: But you realize that this string will throw a parser error?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to retrieve the current HTML from creatediv using `creatediv.innerHTML`.

```
var creatediv=document.createElement("DIV");
var html="<div align=\"left\"><a id=\"test\" >test</a></div>";
creatediv.innerHTML=html;
creatediv.innerText="testing";
html = creatediv.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just overwritten your `innerHTML` at line 4. So your `innerHTML` value in question will be equal to 'testing' string, given your DOM implementation supports non-standard property `innerText` or equal to `html` variable value otherwise.

Comment: here i dont want only testing,i need entire html div with thw updated value testing.

Comment: i dont understand,what is your comment is here.

Answer (score 0):

Append the creatediv to dom tree first, then retrieve by function getElementById.

```
document.append(creatediv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a function that converts value to a string if it's not one. An empty string is returned for null or undefined value:

```
function baseToString(value) {
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
        return value;
    }
    return value == null ? '' : value + '';
}
```